# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when run Mule apllication from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mule, classnotfoundexception

Collegues, i am trying to run Mule application in IntelliJ IDEA. I configured Run Configuration:

```
 Main class: org.mule.MuleServer
   VM options: -Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true
   Program arguments:  -config \src\main\app\mule-config.xml
   Working directory:  C:\Users\Maya\app-services
   JRE: Default (1.8 - SDK of 'app-services' module)
```

When i run then receive next stack trace: http://pastebin.com/24Mf3bsy

What i need to check and correct?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a classpath issue. Is `org.mule.MuleServer` in your classpath?

Comment: I looked into system variables, to Path variable and there is nothing about Mule. Also it worked in Eclipse.

Comment: I've not used IntelliJ. I was referring to Eclipse build path. I guess a similar functionality could be present in IntelliJ to refer the external jars.

Answer (score 0):

I my case:

1. Set Up Run Configuration as desribed in question above
2. Presse F4 on the Project
3. Change all Maven libraries from `provided` to `compile`.
4. Press Ok. Run Application.

   [image: project structure]